# small basic reset shape position after it got out of the screen

Tags: smallbasic

please help!!!!

i'm having a little problem with small basic

i wanted to make a little game where a ufo has to avoid asteroids, and i made an asteroid and animated it, and then i wanted to make its y position go back to 0 wen it passed the screen..

```
meteimg = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\meteo.png"
meteorite = Shapes.AddImage(meteimg)

meteoriteX = Math.GetRandomNumber(GraphicsWindow.Width)
Shapes.Move(meteorite, meteoriteX, 0)
Shapes.Animate(meteorite, meteoriteX, GraphicsWindow.Height,Math.GetRandomNumber(2000))
```

and then i should add something like

```
if meteorite's y position > graphicsWindow.height then
shapes.move(meteorite, meteoriteX, 0)
endif
```

Comment: and i've made this for making the ufo move around, it works but the movement is delayed.. is there any way of fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using shapes.animate for this. You can't get the position of the object while its moving. Here is some code for the astroids:

```
NumAstroids = 10
For i = 1 To NumAstroids
Astroid[i] = Shapes.AddEllipse(20,20)
AstroidX[i] = Math.GetRandomNumber(GraphicsWindow.Width-20)
AstroidY[i] = -Math.GetRandomNumber(GraphicsWindow.Height)
AstroidSpeed[i] = Math.GetRandomNumber(4) + 1 '<- Min speed is 1
EndFor

While 1 = 1
Program.Delay(10)
For i = 1 To NumAstroids
Shapes.Move(Astroid[i],AstroidX[i],AstroidY[i])
AstroidY[i] = AstroidY[i] + AstroidSpeed[i]
 If AstroidY[i] > GraphicsWindow.Height Then
  AstroidX[i] = Math.GetRandomNumber(GraphicsWindow.Width-20)
  AstroidY[i] = -Math.GetRandomNumber(50)-20
  AstroidSpeed[i] = Math.GetRandomNumber(4) + 1 '<- Min speed is 1
 EndIf
EndFor
EndWhile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
meteorite's y position
```

is as far as I know equal to

```
Shapes.GetTop(meteorite)
```

And you need to check that in a loop if it is going to move around.

Comment: I have worked with this, before in a game, you have to use "flags" because the computer doesnt update the screen until after everything has happened. are you working with keybinding events?

Comment: This may be of some help, click on this link to learn about delay and flags->
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/86e2da64-5ad7-42d0-9a25-1b72407a85ef/the-pictures-do-not-want-to-show-up-which-is-because-the-delay-i-have-no-clue-on-how-to-do-this?forum=smallbasic#12d0cb19-5161-41a8-9564-ade533151ab0

Comment: No flags are neccessary, in this case I would recommend a While loop, which regularly checks the position of items. In a best scenario, the same should also be moving them, so the moving items would only have their deltaX and deltaY speed defined. Flags/Events are for user stuff, like mouse clicks. Check out this game: https://mega.nz/#!OJMDWARK!TjgjQzIijkrMOyO_m_O_c1uE413V3BB3n4E8smzPJUI
Its a towerdefence game I havent finished, it won't run on your machine, since it needs some extensions and a lot of graphic files, but inside you will find good principles how to move objects in main loop.

Comment: I see. That would make sense. Good job btw. I made a game that was about 2000+ lines of code. It was a game on fairytale the anime.